# Abstract the same method parameters which are called everytime

Tags: javascript

I have one method that helps responding to requests. Its signature is as follows:

`function render(req, res, data, kind, route)`

It is being called dozens of times with different parameters. I would like to have a cleaner code where I would call

`render(data, kind, route)` knowing that `req` and `res` are always there in the context when calling.

As the following

```
router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
   // some logic
   // render({}, 'kind', 'route') instead of
   render(req, res, {}, 'kind', 'route')
```

Comment: You'd probably add some middleware which injects a pre-bound `render` function into your route handler, e.g. `async function (req, res, next, prebound_render) ...`…

Comment: I hope something like this would be achieved with vanilla JS, playing with context like in closures or currying.

Comment: I can achieve this with closures, but then I need to define each time `outer1 = outerFunc(req, res)` then calling `outer1(data, kind, route)`

Comment: Since `req` and `res` are unique each time your function is invoked, and Javascript doesn't have something like dynamic scoping, this logic must happen somewhere by something that has access to `req` and `res`, but before your function is called. That'd be *middleware*. There's no real sane way to implicitly pass variables in the caller's scope to some function.

Comment: now I'm sure we are aligned on the use case. I will look a bit more though

Comment: It really depends on what exactly `router` is and how its middleware works. I'd hope there's *some* mechanism that allows you to inject something request-specific…

Comment: Alternatively you can always "decorate" your handler directly: `router.get('/', magic_injector(async function (...)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Following @deceze advice. I ended up using a middleware that is attaching a closure as the following

```
const makeRenderer = (req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.renderer = (data, kind, route) => renderer(req, res, data, kind, route)
  next()
}


router.get('/', makeRenderer, async function (req, res, next) {
  const listings = await mongoQueries.getDocumentsSince(
    20, '', req.body.pagination)
  const { page, perPage } = req.body.pagination
  const data = {
    listings: listings.documents,
    addressPoints: [],
    current: page,
    pages: Math.ceil(listings.count / perPage)
  }
  res.locals.renderer(data, 'listings', 'listings')
})
```